# How to access multibyte char from offset 0 in multibyte string?

Tags: php, unicode, multibyte

How to access multibyte char from offset 0 in multibyte string? In my PHP file UTF-8 encoding is used.

```
$month="ř";
echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body>';
die(mb_substr($month,-1,1));
```

This is the printed output: �
Expected output: ř
I am using PHP 5.4 on my localhost.

Comment: Upgrade PHP. It doesn't appear to work in PHP <5.6

Answer (score 0):

Check `mb_internal_encoding()` output and/or your [ini file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset). For PHP 5 UTF-8 could not be default value.

Comment: You can also just force UTF-8 mode, too: https://3v4l.org/Id7B9#v5.4.45 . But I agree, fix this at the config level ideally. Or better, upgrade.